# UIAutomation - Check the message in Alert and compare it with expected message

Tags: ios, uialertview, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am working on alerts in UIAutomation. When I encounter an alert, I am supposed to ensure that the alert title and message are the same as expected. I have done this to get access for alert title.

```
var AlertTitle = target.frontMostApp().alert().name();
UIALogger.logMessage(AlertTitle);
```

In the similar way, is there any way to retrieve the message in alert ? I have tried using

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().value();
```

but it did not work. I have logged the element tree and got this.

```
UIAAlert
 |
 UIAImage
 UIAStaticField name: Abc value: ABc
 UIAStaticField name: XYZ value: XYZ
 UIAButton
```

I need to retrieve the value of second UIAStaticField in this alert and compare with expected value. How do I do that ?

I tried doing this but it didn't work.

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().staticTexts[1]().value();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're so close! You've got the parentheses and brackets backward in your line. Do it this way:

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().staticTexts()[1].value();
```

That way, you are calling the `staticTexts()` method on the alert to get the element array and *then* using the bracket syntax to get the second element.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 7, it appears they wrap the staticTexts in a scrollView, so you'll need to alter Jonathan's answer to be:

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().scrollViews()[0].staticTexts()[1].value();
```